# MODIS NDSI Monthly Map

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap

I'm trying to map monthly NDSI map using MODIS dataset but when I clip it to my area using Snow band, it is showing the band is not found. Here is the code:

```
Map.centerObject(area)
var dataCollection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1')
    .select(['NDSI_Snow_Cover'])

var month_mean = ee.List.sequence(2001, 2020).map(
    function (year) {
        return ee.ImageCollection(
            ee.List.sequence(1,1).map(
                function (month) {
                    var date = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, month, 1);
                    // mean chlor_a (log-normal)
                    var monthMeanImage = dataCollection.filterDate(date, date.advance(1, 'month')).sum().rename('precipitation');

                    // add time band
                    date = ee.Image(date
                        .difference('2002-01-01', "year"))
                        .double()
                        .rename("time");
                    return date.addBands(monthMeanImage);
                })).sum().set('system:time_start', ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1));
    });

var collection = ee.ImageCollection(month_mean).select('NDSI_Snow_Cover');

var januaryMean = collection.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()).clip(area)

Map.addLayer(januaryMean)
```

The link for GEE is:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/311cab2c459081a2f1e2fedf41b554ce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `month_mean`, you have the following line:

```
var monthMeanImage = dataCollection.filterDate(date, date.advance(1, 'month')).sum().rename('precipitation');
```

You're reducing the ImageCollection and renaming the output as `'precipitation'`, so either change that line or change:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection(month_mean).select('NDSI_Snow_Cover');
```

To:

```
var collection = ee.ImageCollection(month_mean).select('precipitation');
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes I used this code for precipitation but could not recognized it.